# How can I output specific bitstream of data to a SFP+ NIC module?

Tags: nic, fiber

I want to output a stream of 1's and 0's to a fiber optic SFP+ module through a NIC connected to my workstation computer ( can be Windows or CentOS/Linux),  where and how do I get started?  Any name of software to use for this? Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For a commercial NIC, this is not possible. The NIC ASIC will only generate full Ethernet frames, encoded with 64b/66b line code. Unless maybe you have access to the manufacturer's internal NIC ASIC documentation. And even then, it likely won't be possible.

I recommend using an FPGA board.

Comment: ok I see, many thanks.   I see that there's also scrambling(deterministic?) of the 64b/66b data packets.    I think it's okay if frames and scrambling occur, as long as there is a gauranteed section of 1's (output light held high) long enough, from a calculation I think there are enough consecutive 1's (https://leventozturk.com/engineering/crc/) if I send data packets which have all 1's.  Is there a suggested software for this?  I see that wireshark is for monitoring, not sending data. Should I be looking at http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/ ? I see it's for 100Mbps, any pitfalls?

Comment: The scrambling is deterministic, but it's done with a linear feedback shift register and so depends on the initial state and the previously transmitted data.  And there is likely no way to see what the initial state was, or know precisely when data was sent.  The whole point of 64b/66b is to limit the length of runs of 1s or 0s (ensure minimum transition density, at least one transition every 66 bits) to enable clock recovery, as well as balance the number of 1s and 0s to eliminate any DC offset shift.

Comment: re: "And there is likely no way to see what the initial state was, or know precisely when data was sent. "  ah I see, good point.   However, if I send continuous packets of "1's" only, the 64b/66b shift registers seem to look as far back as the previous 58th bit, if I deterministically keep sending all 1's, at some point I know enough of what the window that the scrambler sees is, and then is that enough to know that I have a gauranteed certain length of 1's?

Comment: No.  You will never know the scrambler state, or be able to force it to something known, because the output of the scrambler is XORed with the data and fed back around as the input to the scrambler.

Comment: re:  " No. You will never know the scrambler state, or be able to force it to something known ". got it, you're right- thinking through this more thoroughly, I realize that with a constant input, the output sequence will be periodic, but that periodicity is actually 2^N-1 and the entropy is of course high. Thanks a lot for setting me on the right track!